# Nested scripts inside while read file

Tags: bash

I have 3 scripts:

foo1.sh - while reading each line of a file calls the script foo2.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

SCRIPT_DIR="$(cd "$(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")" && pwd)"
I=1

while read LINE  || [ -n "$LINE" ]; do
    ID=$(printf "%05d\n" $I)
    ((I++))
    IDS=($(awk -F "," '{print $1; print $2}' <<< $LINE))

    $SCRIPT_DIR/foo2.sh $ID ${IDS[0]} ${IDS[1]} '-hello'
done < $SCRIPT_DIR/a.txt
```

foo2.sh - calls the script foo3.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

SCRIPT_DIR="$(cd "$(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")" && pwd)"

$SCRIPT_DIR/foo3.sh $1 $2 $3 $4
```

foo3.sh - calls a function that logs stuff

```
#!/bin/bash

info(){
    echo "[INFO][${ARG1}|${ARG2}|${ARG3}] - $1"
}

ARG1=$1
ARG2=$2
ARG3=$3
ARG4=$4

info "START"
info "END"
```

And I have the file a.txt with the following data:

```
foo11,foo12
foo21,foo22
```

When I run ./foo1.sh, the following occurs:

```
] - START001|foo11|foo12
] - END00001|foo11|foo12
[INFO][00002|foo21|foo22] - START
[INFO][00002|foo21|foo22] - END
```

I don't understand why. If I echo every ARG of foo3, they are correct.
If I create the same function in foo2, the output is correct.

Is it because of the \n in the 1st line in the a.txt?

Comment: This might help: [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)

Comment: Thanks, apparently the first line is called like this ./foo2.sh 00001 foo11 $'foo12\r' -hello. Still don't know why

Comment: I found out that the problem was the line ending that had the windows format. I changed to LN and now it works. Thanks Cyrus for the link, it help a lot.